# The right answer..?

Tags: riddle

What is the right answer for the riddle: Divided by a wall? (written by Mc Kevin)

I remember hearing this riddle when I was young.

> Divided by a wall, N and S.
> Tunnels in between, but no one can pass(through me).
>
> The West has more(of me), and the East has less(of me).
> Less is more, but More is less.
>
> What am I, can you guess?

Hint 1:

> I have a rectangular border

Comment: Hi Lisa, welcome to Puzzling! Unfortunately your question is essentially a repost of an already existing question, so I've closed it as an exact duplicate. Also, it's hard to know what the 'right'/intended answer to the puzzle was, unless McKevin comes back to mark an answer as correct. (Finally, the puzzle was posted by McKevin alone; Doorknob only edited it.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I was very curious about that 'right' answer.. Maybe McKevin will tell us :)!

Comment: I just left a comment asking McKevin to either accept a correct answer or add a hint to his question.

Comment: That's really kind of you! Thanks :) I'm very curious..